# Wifi is disabled at every startup

Tags: 12.04

I have updated my Ubuntu OS with kernel 3.9 from Ubuntu main line kernel PPA..The problem  I am facing now is , my wifi is disabled at every startup. however I can enable my wifi by using `rfkill unblock all` .I have searched a lot but cannot find solution.I am using Intel iwl-wifi driver.

Thank you.